# Can I detect UITableView delegates in parent class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have a ViewController that imports two TableViewControllers.

I have the delegate/datasource methods executing in these subclasses, but is there anyway that the ViewController can tell when the each TableView has executed methods such as the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath or do I have to add methods in each tableviewcontroller for polling if cells had been selected?

Thanks!

Comment: u need to trigger the UITableView delegates in parent class?

Comment: @Ramshad I don't need to trigger the delegates, but I just want to the parent class to check if cells has been selected so depending on whether or not they have selected cells, I will enable previously disabled buttons to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own notifications, e.g. "MyDidSelectRowAtIndexPathNotification", and make your main view controller an observer of this notification:

```
#define kMyDidSelectNotification @"MyDidSelectRowAtIndexPathNotification"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(myDidSelectAction:) name:kMyDidSelectNotification object:nil];
```

Then, in your implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you can simply trigger this notification for all observers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:kMyDidSelectNotification object:nil];
```

You can see here that you could pass the `UITableViewCell` or some other object in the notification, if you need it. Your handler for the notification (`myDidSelectAction:` in this case) receives an `NSNotification` object which would contain your object passed in the postNotification operation.

While a protocol would also work, it is more complicated to setup, in my view.

Have a look at the docs for [Notification Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. It was easy to setup. Is there any benefits of doing it with a protocol vs NSNotification?

Comment: If you define a protocol, then you can define precisely the APIs you want to expose along with as many arguments as you want those APIs to receive. Notifications allow for passing _one_ object, not many, but in many cases, _one_ is all you need. In your example, it seems like you have one central object that wants to be notified by a couple other distinct objects. It's "easier" then to have those other objects just make a notification for whatever other objects are interested (your main object in this case). Much less code too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

well you can create a `@protocol` like this:

```
@protocol MyChildViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)tablView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowInChildViewControllerAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
@end
```

now make a property of `MyChildViewControllerDelegate` in class `ChildViewController` and `@synthesize` it, like this:

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) id<MyChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Now when making an instance of `ChildViewController` in parent classes assign the delegate by `self` like this:

```
ChildViewController *ch = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithBlahBlah];
ch.delegate = self;
```

and implement the `MyChildViewControllerDelegate` methods.

now when you receive any `UITableViewDelegate` callback in `ChildViewController` tell your parent classes through delegates.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iPath
{
      [delegate tablView:tView didSelectRowInChildViewControllerAtIndexPath:iPath];
}
```

instead of making your own `MyChildViewControllerDelegate` you can use apple provided `UITableViewDelegate` too (as you find comfort with).

Hope it helps :)